# Sed - How to switch two words in a line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to write a shell script that switches the first and third words in a line. In this case only strings that contain letters (both upper- and lowercase) count as words, everything else (numbers, punctuation, whitespace) is considered whitespace.
For example:

```
abc123def. ghi...jkl
```

would turn into:

```
ghi123def. abc...jkl
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
sed 's/\([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*\)[^A-Z^a-z]\([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*\)[^A-Z^a-z]\([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*\)/\3 \2 \1/' input.txt
```

Comment: Does it need to be sed?  Awk is generally more suited to treating lines as sequences of words.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ echo "abc123def. ghi...jkl" | sed -r 's/([A-Za-z]*)([^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]*[^A-Za-z]*)([A-Za-z]*)(.*)/\3\2\1\4/g'
$ ghi123def. abc...jkl
```

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't _quite_ what I needed, but only because I wasn't clear that the lines don't necessarily start with a word. Here is the variation I went with: `sed -r 's/([^A-Za-z]*)([A-Za-z]+)([^A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z]+[^A-Za-z]+)([A-Za-z]+)(.*)/\1\4\3\2\5/g'`